# iTextSharp stops after 2 pages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to convert **HTML to PDF with iTextSharp**.
Here's my code:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
StringReader reader = new StringReader(responseHtml);
FileStream pdfStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\foo.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, pdfStream);

doc.Open();
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, reader);
doc.Close();
```

The issue is that the **PDF file stops after 2 pages**.
The rest of the content just doesn't make it to the PDF file.
When  I change the PageSize to A1, I get the whole content, 'cause it fits on two A1 pages.
**How** do I get it to **create more than two pages?**

Comment: Conclusion: the ParseXHtml method is a piece of crap. While it's valid xhtml & css, pages get cut off for no real reason, many style elements are ignored, valid changes to the pages break it.. After hours of utter frustration, I used another library.

Comment: Which library did you end up using? I have the same problem with iTextSharp, but not just after 2 pages. Sometimes it will render 6 pages without a hick-up, other times it will render 4 but cut out the remaining 2 pages. And it always happens at a page break. BTW: the same data will cut at the same place every time, it's not randomly happening.

Comment: I'm sure there are cleaner solutions, but I went with wrapping the execution of `wkhtmtopdf` inside a `Process` within a class. That's the free option, there are paid options as well.